# Creating a continues loop with try | Python3

Tags: python-3.x, loops, try-catch

I'm trying to receive user input that has to be between 2 and 10 and then return a message if the input is in fact between 2 and 10.

**What I'm struggling with:**

if the user inputs something other than a number, I get a ValueError

**How I'm trying to resolve it:**

I use the try except finally method.

**Issue I'm unable to resolve:**

When the user inputs a letter, the first time around, it will bring up the *try:* but if the user then inputs a letter a second time, it will give an error once again.

How can I make this loop so the user can give as many wrong answers as he wants and get it to it's final destination once he inputs a value between 2 and 10?

**My code so far**

```
try:
    user_input = input("give a number between 2 and 10: ")
    while 10 < int(user_input) or int(user_input) < 2:
        user_input = input("No no, a number between 2 and 10!: ")
except ValueError:
    print(f"That wasn\'t a number! Try again.")
    user_input = input("give a number between 2 and 10: ")
    while 10 < int(user_input) or int(user_input) < 2:
        user_input = input("No no, a number between 2 and 10!: ")
finally:
    print("Good, welcome to the dark side.")
```

Would appreciate the help!

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use try-exception only for this?

Answer (score 0):

This example works, while making minimal changes to your code:

```
while True:
    try:
        user_input = input("give a number between 2 and 10: ")
        while 10 < int(user_input) or int(user_input) < 2:
            user_input = input("No no, a number between 2 and 10!: ")
        break

    except ValueError:
        print(f"That wasn\'t a number! Try again.")

print("Good, welcome to the dark side.")
```

The main differences are removing the while loop from within the `except` and the `finally` portion, and using a `while True` loop to continue asking the question until the conditions are met that lead to the `break` (i.e. user enters a value between 2 and 10, inclusive). My test of this code works.

Comment: Thanks! While that got it into a loop, the next thing I'm trying to do is use the user_input outside of the while loop, so I need to be able to access it outside the while loop, which I can't since it is inside the while loop any ideas on that?